# What to do with Github branches that have been merged to upstream?

Tags: git, github

As I work on a forked github project I have created many branches that I have sent pull-requests on. Once these branches are merged to upstream, they remain in my local and remote repo. What is best practice to do with these branches?

Comment: May be delete them if you think they are not useful in future :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once they are merged, you can safely delete them, as the commits in them are tracked by the main branch in the upstream repo. Keeps things clean. IIRC github even gives you a popup to delete pull request branches.